# Why this code snippet when run in Node print the output and exit without waiting but in Deno it prints the output; waits for some time and then exits

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, settimeout

```
async function quick_function(){
    const x = await Promise.all([sleep(1000), sleep(2000)]);
    console.log(x[0]);
    console.log(x[1]);
}


async function sleep(time){
    const x = await new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(resolve(time),time);
    });
    return x;
}


async function lazy_function(){
    await sleep(2000);
    await sleep(3000);
    console.log("finally");
}



quick_function();
lazy_function();
```

Please someone explain why the above code snippet when run in Node.js print the output and exit without waiting but in Deno it waits for some time and then exits.

The output

```
1000
2000
finally
```

Comment: It shouldn't compile in TypeScript at all. `setTimeout` takes a function, not `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sleep` function is not working as expected. You must wrap the `resolve` in a lambda to have it works as intended:

```js
async function quick_function(){
    const x = await Promise.all([sleep(1000), sleep(2000)]);
    console.log(x[0]);
    console.log(x[1]);
}


async function sleep(time){
    const x = await new Promise((resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(() => resolve(time), time);
    });
    return x;
}


async function lazy_function(){
    await sleep(2000);
    await sleep(3000);
    console.log("finally");
}

quick_function();
lazy_function();
```

In this fixed code, both `node` and `deno` will behave similarly.

As for why there was a timing difference in the original code between the two runtimes, I feel it must be related on the way `deno` introduced `top-level await` capability recently.